# decoding of APE (Monkey's Audio) using FFmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decoding

I am developing a player which plays different audio formats,I have successfully played mp3,acc,wav,ogg,alac,flac formats. But now stuck on **APE** or **Monkey's Audio** format, I am using a open source library FFmpeg for decoding.Can someone tell me how to decode APE format,I   am successful in creating the packets,storing in a buffer and passing it to FFmpeg in the same fashion as I did for other formats,but FFMpeg is not able to decode those packets.Can someone tell me what wrong I am doing? What should be the buffer size in case of ape that needs to be passed to ffmpeg.Also header parsing, The decode function of ffmpeg is **avcodec_decode_audio3**.